# How do I switch from git existing repo and init new one as I can keep all activity of my project in a same online repo

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

I have already  one git online repo of my project where I only kept my client side data but later I have created server folder to make my backhand activity separately. Under my PersonalWebsite folder I have created two folder which are client and  server respectively. I have been working for long time on client folder and already init it at to online repo but while I go to init my other folder such as server, first one is switched and second one placed into that repo.

i want to keep both folder server and client in a same repo but doing some step using git command and pushed it to online repo now I see that both of my server and client data not showing in git  online repo.

Whats the solution for that I actually want to keep my project all activity such as server and client in a same repo.

Follwing some piture I am showing...

My git online repo in bitbucet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwbwS.png)

Marked option is my project folder server and myweb where no data is found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3H0c.png)

This is my file structure on vs code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8o3J.png)

This is my first init project into git repo and its package.json file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQfI1.png)

This is my server folder package.json file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKDY4.png)

To say precisely.....
First I init myweb folder to online repo.
now I need to keep both server and myweb folder in same repo.
PersonalWebsite> server + myweb

Now I have to init PersonalWebsite folder

After doing that into other online repo there I can not see my previous activity done both folder like server and myweb

Comment: look into git sub modules

Comment: But I already init my root folder where both of of my project file I mean client+server exist and forcefully push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After once init a file into git of a project and there will be some change or need to add another folder/file with the existing git repo, solution can be like that...

Go to root folder like PersonalWebsite in the terminal...

write, step-1,

```
rm -rf .git
```

then step-2

```
git init
```

then, put

```
git add .
```

then commit ,

```
git commit -m "Text"
```

then type

```
git remote add origin <"url">
```

finally push it by force...

```
git push -f origin master
```

Now I hope everything will be fine, this solution only for submodule adding into git and one of them already initialized but other not ...then we can include like git both folder discussed above myweb+server in a same online repo under rootFolder....

There all the steps are needed to apply after by switching into rooFolder

I mean,type in terminal like..

```
cd roorFolder or PersonalWebsite
```

Afterwards, follow discussed command...

Thank you.